# Display 5th level of category

Tags: magento-2.1, drop-downs, megamenu

I am using Magento 2 and I want to display `5 level` of categories.

[image]

```
(1)Shop->(2)shop->(3)audio->(4)Test->(5)test1
```

I tried below code but 5th level of categories is not display accurate :

```
public function simpletMenu($category)
    {
        $categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
        $catHtml = '';
        // 2nd Level Category
        if ($childrenCategories = $this->getChildCategories($category)) {
            $catHtml .= '<ul class="rootmenu-submenu">';
            foreach ($childrenCategories as $childCategory) {
                $collection_sub = $this->getChildCategories($childCategory);
                if (count($collection_sub)) {
                    $arrow = '<span class="cat-arrow"></span>';
                } else { 
                    $arrow = '';
                }
                $catHtml .= '<li><a href="'.$categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childCategory).'">'.$childCategory->getName().$arrow.'</a>';

                    // 3rd Level Category
                    if (count($collection_sub)) {
                        $catHtml .= '<ul class="rootmenu-submenu-sub">';
                            foreach ($collection_sub as $childCategory2) {
                                $collection_sub_sub = $this->getChildCategories($childCategory2);
                                if (count($collection_sub_sub)) {
                                    $arrow = '<span class="cat-arrow"></span>';
                                } else {
                                    $arrow = '';
                                }
                                $catHtml .= '<li><a href="'.$categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childCategory2).'">'.$childCategory2->getName().$arrow.'</a>';

                                // 4th Level Category
                                if (count($collection_sub_sub)) {
                                    $catHtml .= ' <ul class="rootmenu-submenu-sub-sub">';
                                        foreach ($collection_sub_sub as $childCategory3) {
                                            $collection_sub_sub_sub = $this->getChildCategories($childCategory3);
                                        if (count($collection_sub_sub_sub)) {
                                            $arrow = '<span class="cat-arrow"></span>';
                                        } else {
                                            $arrow = '';
                                        }
                                            $catHtml .= '<li><a href="'.$categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childCategory3).'">'.$childCategory3->getName().$arrow.'</a>';

                                    // 4th Level Category
                                    if (count($collection_sub_sub_sub)) {
                                        $catHtml .= ' <ul class="rootmenu-submenu-sub-sub-sub">';
                                            foreach ($collection_sub_sub_sub as $childCategory4) {
                                                $catHtml .= '<li><a href="'.$categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childCategory4).'">'.$childCategory4->getName().'</a></li>';
                                             }
                                        $catHtml .= '</ul>';
                                    }   
                                            $catHtml .= '</li>';
                                         }
                                    $catHtml .= '</ul>';
                                }
                                $catHtml .= '</li>';
                             }
                        $catHtml .= '</ul>';
                    }
                $catHtml .= '</li>';
            }
            $catHtml .= '</ul>';
        }
        return $catHtml;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a category collection in your **block**, then you filter per level `addLevelFilter()` after that you get that function in your phtml like this:

`$block->getCategoryLevelCollection($level)`

```
public function getCategoryLevelCollection($level)
{
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1')
        ->addLevelFilter($level);
    return $collection;
}
```